# error when switching to insert mode of vim after installing a github config

Tags: python-3.x, vim, config, vim-plugin, ultisnips

I am currently installing a vim config by the name of [vimcake](https://github.com/ChuOkupai/vimcake). Once the installation is done when I try to write to a file by switching to insert mode this error is displayed permanently. Would you have any information on this? I'm on macOS and using the native version of vim and it looks like Python 3.7.3 is on the machine.
Thank you

[image: screen of error message]

Comment: The default Vim is not  built with Python support. Get MacVim. Also, consider learning Vim instead of using someone else's config.

Comment: Installing a vim setup from github doesn't mean I don't know how to use vim at all. I think it's more a way to save time in a certain context and to take advantage of the work and experience of others to focus on other tasks with added value, a bit like when you give a little of your time to answer one of my questions and I thank you.